# no such table: main.auth_user__old

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I ran this commnad and there was no problem

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

then I ran and did as username, email and password:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

but when I went to admin panel and try new content and I got this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/..../..../add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

Django version 2.1.4
Python version 3.7

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old can help you?

Comment: For me the issue was the order that the migrations were ran in - I needed to run the default django migrations first, and then run my site migrations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58519187/5328951 it should work

Answer (score 1):

Update Django to 2.1.5 version.