# When I try to add new category in django admin, OperationalError at /admin/mediaportalapp/category/add/

Tags: django, python-3.x, manjaro

I made new project on django, added two models and registered them in admin.
When I try to add something in admin panel I recieve error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/mediaportalapp/category/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/mediaportalapp/category/add/
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: /home/arch/Рабочий стол/mediaportal_project/MediaPortalEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 296
Python Executable:  /home/arch/Рабочий стол/mediaportal_project/MediaPortalEnv/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path:    
['/home/arch/Рабочий стол/mediaportal_project/mp_portal',
 '/home/arch/Рабочий стол/mediaportal_project/MediaPortalEnv/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/arch/Рабочий стол/mediaportal_project/MediaPortalEnv/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/arch/Рабочий '
 'стол/mediaportal_project/MediaPortalEnv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/arch/Рабочий '
 'стол/mediaportal_project/MediaPortalEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 22 Dec 2018 14:50:32 +0000
```

I've also tried starting several new project from the scratch with no luck.

Comment: I forgot to tell,table: main.auth_user__old  is a table from my last project

Comment: It's already answered in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old/53896700