# OperationalError at /admin/myschoolweb/album/add/ - no such table: main.auth_user__old

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to add new data in table, but every time it gives below error

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.7.1
Sqlite3 Version: 2.6.0

I have already gone through all the available answers here, but still the issue persists.

I have already followed the steps for 'python manage.py makemigrations' , 'python manage.py migrate'.

i tried to upgrade as well as "downgrade your version of sqlite to a version prior to 2.6 (e.g. 2.5.1)", but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help.

---

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myschoolweb/album/add/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'myschoolweb']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: main.auth_user__old) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  604.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1637.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1525.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1568.                     self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in log_addition
  810.             change_message=message,

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\models.py" in log_action
  35.             change_message=change_message,

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\<USER>\Miniconda3\envs\mywebsite\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/myschoolweb/album/add/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

Comment: run the following command, **`python manage.py migrate`** then try

Comment: as i said earlier, i have already ran the command 'python manage.py makemigrations' and 'python manage.py migrate'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58519187/5328951 it should work

Comment: The issue is solved in the here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old/
its a duplicate of the same

Answer (score 0):

before upgrading Django, do delete db.sqlite3 file and make sure deleting all files except *init*.py under migrations folder, create new db.sqlite3 file and run command python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate.