# Django error: OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/

Tags: django

I have tried to change user permission in the administration page but it actually shows me this when I save

I'm using 
Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.2
for what i saw it was an issue before Django 2.1.5 so I have no idea what to do

```
OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/
no such table: main.auth_permission__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_permission__old
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 298
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['/home/Max/Documents/Workspace/Projet_Python/hey',
 '/usr/lib64/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/Max/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 29 Mar 2019 10:12:07 +0000
```

Comment: have you run migration

Comment: Yes already tried :/

Comment: Your app is not detecting migrations then do  `python manage.py makemigrations appname` then `python manage.py migrate appname`

Comment: As suggested in the comments for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637669/113962): Try deleting the db.sqlite3 file (back it up first if you've got any important data in the db) and re-run `migrate` to create a fresh database.

Comment: deleting db.sqlite3 file works ! thanks !