# How to downgrade sqlite3 that comes with Python and Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, downgrade

So I am stuck in this problem: [Django - No such table: main.auth_user__old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old)

I can't upgrade Django because many other applications are connected to it using version 2.1. The only approach is to edit the sqlite3. Currently, I am using SQLITE3 3.26.0 and I want to downgrade to 2.5.1. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to sqlite?
The error seems more to indicate, that this is a migration issue of the user model

Comment: Because the answer to the same problem indicates that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637669/11496481

Comment: OK. I see.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182 which I found at the url you mentioned, seems to indicate, that's a problem introduced by a migration done while you had a bad combo of django and sqlite.

your link says, that upgrade to 2.1.5+ should fix the issue 

I guess, that upgrading to 2.1.13 should fix the issue for future migrations.

I'm not sure however, whether downgrading /  upgrading will repair an already broken migration. I guess you have either to start with a new fresh database or do some manual fixes to do what the migration failed to do.

Comment: Could you please guide me toward a manual fix or approach to follow in order to fix the problem manually?