# Django error no such table: main.auth_user__old

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm creating my first Django project. I am getting an error when I press the save button after adding the data to the text fields inside the products. This is the error I get:

```
OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/

no such table: main.auth_user__old

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/products/product/add/
Django Version:     2.1
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such table: main.auth_user__old

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Ehtsham\PycharmProjects\firstproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Ehtsham\PycharmProjects\firstproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.1
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\PycharmProjects\\firstproject',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\PycharmProjects\\firstproject\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\PycharmProjects\\firstproject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\PycharmProjects\\firstproject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Ehtsham\\PycharmProjects\\firstproject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg']

Server time:    Sun, 5 Jan 2020 15:00:27 +0000
```

I also did migrations before:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Ehtsham\PycharmProjects\firstproject>python manag
e.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'products':
  products\migrations\0002_offers.py
    - Create model Offers

(venv) C:\Users\Ehtsham\PycharmProjects\firstproject>python manag
e.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, products, sess
ions
Running migrations:
  Applying products.0002_offers... OK
```

I'm using Django version 2.1 and SQLite DB browser on PyCharm IDE.

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrate your database?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old

Comment: Upgrade django and pytz to latest version. Then run migrate. This solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It shows your django version is "**Django Version**:2.1"

You need to  upgrade your django. if its a new project.
Please do the following steps.

step:1>>  `pip install Django --upgrade`

step:2 >>  `python manage.py makemigrations`

Step:3 >>  `python manage.py migrate`

Ste:-4 >>  `python manage.py runserver`