# I'm trying to add new product on my new project. But why it's show (no such table: main.auth_user__old)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add new product details on product table. But whenever I try to save this it's show me

***OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/***

***Here are errors detail: ***
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old

***This is model***

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2088)


class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

***admin***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

Comment: Did you `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes I did all those things

Comment: Post you models and admin. Apparently, there is no table with that name in your database. And that name `main.auth_user__old` looks weird.

Comment: I added models and admin

Comment: Looks like sqlite issue - refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old

Comment: I show this post. But it's not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still struggling with this, but I had the same issue. The solution was deleting and re-downloading `db.sqlite3` with an older version of django.

1. Go to the virtual environment and install django(version 2.1.7)
   `pip install django==2.1.7`
2. Delete the `db.sqlite3` file in your root folder. (Search for it in your PyCharm projects in the root folder if that's where it's stored)
3. Create a new `db.sqlite3` by doing `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. Re-run migrations, after doing `python manage.py makemigrations` run `python manage.py migrate` .