# How to solve an admin operational problem in django?

Tags: python, django, operationalerror

i am working on an django project (website)
i started coding 2 months ago and while working with django project i stucked at a problem.

Actually, I am learning how to make websites, And when i login to admin it works fine but when i add product then it shows

```
[OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 396
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\Pyshop\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Pyshop',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Pyshop\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\PycharmProjects\\Pyshop\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 27 May 2020 04:31:07 +0000][1]
```

Please help me with this

here are those files

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
price = models.FloatField()
stock = models.IntegerField()
image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)


class Offer(models.Model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
discount = models.FloatField(5)
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
return HttpResponse('Hello world')


def new(request):
return HttpResponse('New Products!!!!!!!!!!!!!')


def microsoft(request):
return HttpResponse('microsoft 365')
```

project urls.py:

```
"""pyshop URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('product/', include('product.urls'))
]
```

product.url.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('new/', views.new),
path('microsoft/', views.microsoft)
]
```

here are those views, models. urls files
please solve the problem !!!!

Comment: Have you done `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and `python3 manage.py migrate` before starting server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - No such table: main.auth\_user\_\_old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old)

Comment: yes, i've done that but again the same problem is showing

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have syn your database i.e. by running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If this shows some error or doesn't work then try deleting all migration files and `__pychache__` except `__init__.py` and run makemigrations and migrate commands again.

Comment: i removed all migration files and catch files and run those commands and again the same problem was showing

Comment: Thank You, bhaiya for your concern, i am starting my project from scratch if i face problem then please solve that 
thank you again @Sheraram Prajapat, Pruthvi Barot

Comment: hello i've faced the same problem again after restarting the problem please help me!!! 
this operational error admin/product/add
@Sheraram_Prajapat

Comment: please add your models, views and urls so we may look at where/what is causing problem/error.

Comment: i've posted the files mentioned above in the question only please refer that 
and help me please!!!!!!
And yes i am programming in windows but the tutorial from which i am learning is mac
now please help me!!!!! @Sheraram_Prajapat

Comment: @PiyushJangid Please stop pinging others several time. They are notified the first time and will decide when and if they have time to help. Also, please avoid using the desperate tone and many exclamation marks. It comes across as pretty rude because it can be seen as putting others under pressure - remember, we are all volunteers here with limited time.

Comment: Ok sir, sorry for that i don't know next time i will remember@ModusTollens

Comment: hi please help me with this my project is stucked at this please help me.@Sheraram_Prajapat

Comment: @Piyush Jangid, I haven't encountered such error and whenever I do encounter related to database, I simply delete pychache and migration of apps as well as project and sqlite3 database too, make sure you have Django updated or you can downgrade your Django to version 2. For mare info look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old

Comment: how can i delete sqlite3 file, actually it is not deleting from pycharm IDE,can you tell me how to delete pychache and migration for above both. @Sheraram_Prajapat

Comment: i've updated my django to version 3.0.7 but nothing is working?@Sheraram_Prajapat

Comment: Then I would suggest please start a new project. sorry I can't help you

Comment: i've previously started the new project only 
actually i am creating my project in pycharm IDE and in that my sqlite3 file's icon on pycharm is question mark is showing 
and when i copy sqlite 3 file to db browser then it is showing that 
file is not a database
it is related to database ? @Sheraram_Prajapat

Comment: No idea I don't use pycharm. I use VS Code

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to migrate after creating the models in models.py steps:

1. create the models in models.py
2. go to cmd and go to the path of your project ( the place where you run the server)

3)type the command :python manage.py migrate

4)click enter

4)then type : python manage.py makemigrations

5)in the place of  put the name of your app after that click enter

6)type the command :python manage.py migrate

that's all and the problem is solved