# Operational error while adding values in a text field in django

Tags: python, django

I get this error when I add a something to the text field.I'm trying to create a project where someone can enter random messages.

```
OperationalError at /admin/submit/submit/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/submit/submit/add/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: D:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
Python Executable:  D:\Anaconda1\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\PyProjects\\Website',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\python38.zip',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\lib',
 'D:\\Anaconda1',
 'C:\\Users\\heman\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\lib\\site-packages',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'D:\\Anaconda1\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Mon, 5 Oct 2020 17:19:26 +000
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Submit(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
    status = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
```

Here is my setting.py installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'submit.apps.SubmitConfig',
]
```

Here is my apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class SubmitConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'submit'
```

Here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Submit

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Submit)
```

I also ran python manage.py makemigrations
and python manage.py migrate
Please help me...Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` and show input, please

Comment: ```D:\PyProjects\Website>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

D:\PyProjects\Website>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, submit
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
``` @FedorSoldatkin

Comment: Edit: Now if I enter data in the database, the change and value is being reflected in the admin panel. But still I'm not able to dynamically add value to the submit via admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me..
the original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349457/13732795
But I'll copy paste it here too

1. Go to the virtual environment and install django@2.1.7
   `pip install django==2.1.7`
2. Delete the `db.sqlite3` file in your root folder.
3. Create the new `db.sqlite3` in your root folder.
4. Re-run migrations:

`python manage.py makemigrations`
 `python manage.py migrate`