# Can't add new user or group in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add new user and group in my newly created django web from admin panel . But it shows following error when I click save.

[This the admin panel of my django website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9FE9.png)

[Here new group "group1" is creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4rGH.png)

> OperationalError at /admin/auth/group/add/ no such table:
> main.auth_user__old Request Method:   POST Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/group/add/ Django Version: 2.1.5
> Exception Type:   OperationalError Exception Value:    no such table:
> main.auth_user__old Exception
> Location: G:\MyPythonProject\django_web\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py
> in execute, line 298 Python
> Executable:   G:\MyPythonProject\django_web\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.9.0 Python Path:
> ['G:\MyPythonProject\django_web\web_project',
> 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
> 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
> 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
> 'G:\MyPythonProject\django_web\venv',
> 'G:\MyPythonProject\django_web\venv\lib\site-packages'] Server
> time: Sat, 12 Dec 2020 18:18:33 +0000

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old Surely this might help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - No such table: main.auth\_user\_\_old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old)

Comment: No I have tried those. But didn't work.