# I am getting this operational error while making my web app

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning Python from a course Python by code with Mosh. In his course he has explained to build a web app using Django. While I was running my app on web server, I got an error "OPERATIONALERROR" and now I am stuck in it.

A picture of error I am receiving:

[image]

Comment: Only add respective programming language tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Django bug.

[Related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old).

The solution as can be seen from the link is:

```
pip install Django --upgrade
```

Then:

```
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py makemigrations app

python manage.py migrate
```