# Unable to delete a user in django's built in auth app

Tags: python, django, sqlite

When I try to delete a user from Django's built in auth app, I have this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.auth_user__old`

I searched on the web and I found this question : [Django - No such table: main.auth_user__old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old)
So I updated Django and I am now using the version 3.2.4 (I am using sqlite). Then I tried to delete auth tables from the db but when I did a `ptyhon manage.py makemigrations auth`, it told me that no changes were detected.
Also, I can't delete the whole database.

Does someone have an idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Try `python manage.py migrate auth zero --fake` and then `python manage.py migrate`. You really shouldn't go and delete the tables yourself, the migration system can do that easily.

Comment: Thank you @AbdulAzizBarkat, it worked ! However, the tables were not deleted automatically with your command, I had to do it again by hand. Does it have something to do with the '--fake' tag ?

Comment: I thought you had _already_ deleted the tables? That is why I included `--fake` in the command.

Comment: Yes I had already deleted them, but because nothing worked, I restored an old version of the database to try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be deleting tables manually while using Django. Django adds an extra table to the database called `django_migrations` and in this table Django keeps track of which migrations are applied. When you manually delete stuff their entry is *still* left in this table and hence you find yourself unable to apply migrations.

The simplest way to do what you want is to *reverse* the migrations by migrating to a previous migration by specifying the migration name:

```
python manage.py [app_label] [migration_name]
```

You can use `zero` as the `migration_name` to reverse *all* migrations. If suppose you have already changed things manually you can use the `--fake` flag to fake the migrations (Which will simply mark / unmark the migrations as applied). Considering you already deleted the tables you can use the following command:

```
python manage.py migrate auth zero --fake
```

For more information on the `migrate` command you can read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate).