# Django - OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/ no such table: main.auth_user__old

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on my first Django project, and I'm following the tutorial guide made by Mosh in his video in Python for Beginners. The project is an online shop and I keep getting stuck when I'm adding new products to my products list(video time stamp - 5:41:07). I followed all his steps but kept getting stuck on the same part no matter how I looked for the answer.

```
OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: D:\programming\phython projects\project_5(PyShop)\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 477, in execute
Python Executable:  D:\programming\phython projects\project_5(PyShop)\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\programming\\phython projects\\project_5(PyShop)',
 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'D:\\programming\\phython projects\\project_5(PyShop)',
 'D:\\programming\\phython projects\\project_5(PyShop)\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 19 May 2022 07:49:11 +0000
```

this is my line of code

views module in products package:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Products')
```

url module in products package:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new', views.new)
]
```

modules module in pyshop package:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

modules module in pyshop package:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProductsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'products'
```

urls module in pyshop package:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

admin.py module in pyshop package:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product


admin.site.register(Product)
```

I also made sure to input these two lines before opening the live server:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app

python manage.py migrate app
```

Comment: seems this answering your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637182/django-no-such-table-main-auth-user-old?rq=1

Comment: can you send your admin.py too?

Comment: Xeus, just edited the question so now there is admin.py